# SQL query: strange SUM behaviour

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm running this query

```
SELECT events.*, venues.*,
    SUM(events.eventCAPACITY) AS capacity,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.bookingAMOUNT is NULL THEN 0 ELSE bookings.bookingAMOUNT END) AS booked,
    SUM(events.eventCAPACITY) - SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.bookingAMOUNT is NULL THEN 0 ELSE bookings.bookingAMOUNT END) AS available
FROM events
LEFT JOIN bookings ON events.eventID = bookings.bookingEVENT
LEFT JOIN venues ON venues.venueID = events.eventVENUE
WHERE events.eventDATE >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY events.eventID
ORDER BY events.eventDATE, events.eventTIME ASC
```

Everything goes well. Except when events.eventCAPACITY (e.g. 20) has been reached (via another table), it doesn't give zero, it just gives the amount set in events.eventCAPACITY again (20).

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

This is the result I get from running the query.

| eventID | eventDATUM | eventTIJDSTIP | eventVENUE | eventCAPACITY | venueID | venueNAME | capacity | booked | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-24 | 12:00:00 | 1 | 15 | 1 | Venue1 | 15 | 0 | 15 |
| 2 | 2021-01-24 | 11:00:00 | 2 | 15 | 2 | Venue2 | 15 | 0 | 15 |
| 3 | 2021-01-13 | 09:00:00 | 1 | 15 | 1 | Venue1 | 30 | 15 | 15 |

the expected result of the third row should be capacity 15 instead of 30 and available should be 0 instead of 15.

And these are the tables.

table bookings

| bookingID | bookingFIRSTNAME | bookingLASTNAME | bookingEMAIL | bookingEVENT | bookingAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | John | Smith | john.smith@gmail.com | 3 | 10 |
| 27 | Jane | Smith | jane.smith@qsg.com | 3 | 5 |

table events

| eventID | eventDATE | eventTIME | eventVENUE | eventCAPACITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-24 | 12:00:00 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 2021-01-24 | 11:00:00 | 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 2021-01-13 | 09:00:00 | 1 | 15 |

table venues

table venues

| venueID | venueNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Venue1 |
| 2 | Venue2 |
| 3 | Venue3 |

Comment: What do you mean by "eventCAPACITY has been reached"?  Do you mean that `capacity` and `booked` are equal?  Are you referring to the value of `available`?  What do you see as `capacity` and `booked` and what do you see as `available`?

Comment: Any irregularity you are seeing in aggregation is possibly due to the fact that you have many columns in the `SELECT` list which are not also in `GROUP BY`. MySQL has a lenient behavior by default (in less recent versions anyway) which allows you to have used `GROUP BY events.eventID` without needing `GROUP BY events.eventID, events.somethingElse, venues.venueID, etc, etc, etc` -- Without seeing samples from you original tables or a sample of your output, I am very suspicious of your GROUP BY.

Comment: You should post a small representative sample of the tables involved in this query together with 1) the result exact result those sample rows produce now and 2) exactly what you expect the result to be

Comment: I added some more info, tables and results.

Comment: Why are you using `SUM()` on `events.eventCAPACITY`?  Aren't you grouping by `eventID`?  So, there should only be one needed value of `eventCAPACITY`, you don't need `SUM()` there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `SUM()` for `events.eventCAPACITY`.  The `JOIN`s may be creating duplicate values (that you can see if you were to use `GROUP_CONCAT(events.eventCAPACITY`).

The solution here is to just drop the `SUM()` around `events.eventCAPACITY`

```
SELECT events.*, venues.*,
    events.eventCAPACITY AS capacity,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.bookingAMOUNT is NULL THEN 0 ELSE bookings.bookingAMOUNT END) AS booked,
    events.eventCAPACITY - SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.bookingAMOUNT is NULL THEN 0 ELSE bookings.bookingAMOUNT END) AS available
FROM events
LEFT JOIN bookings ON events.eventID = bookings.bookingEVENT
LEFT JOIN venues ON venues.venueID = events.eventVENUE
WHERE events.eventDATE >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY events.eventID
ORDER BY events.eventDATE, events.eventTIME ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have got a lot to learn about this.